# Issue inserting data using mysqli in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, insert

I try to use `mysqli` in order to insert data in my database. But does not work. Where may be the error?

```
$myDb = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

if($myDb->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $myDb->connect_error . ']');
}

$statment = $myDb->prepare("INSERT INTO user(name,surname,age)
VALUES (?,?,?)");
  $statement->bind_param('s', $_POST['name']);
  $statement->bind_param('s', $_POST['surname']);
  $statement->bind_param('i', 25);


  $statement->execute();

  $statement->free_result();
```

EDIT:

I obtain this error:

```
Binding parameters failed: (0) Execute failed: (2031) No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement
```

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` tell you?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Binding parameters failed: (0) Execute failed: (2031) No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem using a correct bind of parameter. Here the correct code:

```
$myDb = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

if($myDb->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $myDb->connect_error . ']');
}

$statment = $myDb->prepare("INSERT INTO user(name,surname,age)
VALUES (?,?,?)");
  $statement->bind_param('s', $name);
  $statement->bind_param('s', $surname);
  $statement->bind_param('i', $age);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$age  = 25;


  $statement->execute();

  $statement->free_result();
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the error here:

$statement->bind_param('i', 25);

25 is not a variable. You can only use variables when binding parameters. You can't use constants nor fixed strings or numbers when binding.

Besides, it never worked for me to split the parameters when binding. I got an error. I need to do so:

```
$myDb = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

if($myDb->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $myDb->connect_error . ']');
}

$statement = $myDb->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name,surname,age) VALUES (?,?,25)");
$statement->bind_param('ss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['surname']);

$statement->execute();

$statement->free_result();
$statement->close();
```